# title and description for camera click images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

In my camera app i want when i click an image it will ask for title and description from the user and then save it.right now its saving images but not asking for title and description.I am new to iOS.so,may be this is a silly question.please help me to get this.for camera click i am using this method:-

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

BOOL camera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
if(camera)
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [[picker navigationBar]setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    [picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this tutorial guided me to achieve what i want.So, i think to share the link.May be someone gets benefited.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22

and this piece of code helps me out..

```
-(void) takePhoto{
    BOOL camera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    if(camera)
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [[picker navigationBar]setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [picker setDelegate:self];
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        [picker release];
        actionSheetbool = false;
    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView* cameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!!" message:@"Camera not found." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [cameraAlert show];
        [cameraAlert release];
    }

}
-(void)photoLibrary{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        [imagePicker release];
        actionSheetbool = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

- Click the image using camera.
- Come back to your app without saving the image. You'll have a reference of the image clicked in your application till now.
- ask the user for the title & description.
- Save the image to picture library using this line of code:

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void  contextInfo);

Hope it helps you.

[More Help Here....](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I m new to iOS.So,if possible can you guide me how to write the code for this problem??